# eclipse uninstall plugin fail under jrockit

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I encountered problem uninstalling eclipse plugin using jrockit vm instead of hotspot vm.

It fails with following exception:

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.sonatype.tycho.m2e 0.6.0.201207302152, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: %23c:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/javaw.exe
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: %23c:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/javaw.exe
```

When I change vm back to hotspot this problem disappears.

```
-vm
c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/javaw.exe
#c:/Program Files/Java/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_33-R28.2.4-4.1.0/bin/javaw.exe
```

Comment: I believe this because you cannot use a comment on that position - simply remove the original `c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/javaw.exe` line (as it says: there is an invalid character `#` at the beginning). Btw it seems it is rather an issue in the `m2e` plugin (or it is a faulty configuration and this plugin faced the issue for the first time).

Comment: What a pita! It really drove me nuts...
@rlegendi Why not create a full answer, it solved my problem as well :)

Comment: @user462982 Done that :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this because you cannot use a comment on that position - simply remove the original `c:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_26/bin/javaw.exe` line (as it says: there is an invalid character `#` at the beginning). Btw it seems it is rather an issue in the m2e plugin (or it is a faulty configuration and this plugin faced the issue for the first time).